# SQL Oracle - query to return rows based on data matchng rules

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below data

```
NUMBER      SEQUENCE_NUMBER
CA00000045  AAD508
CA00000045  AAD508
CA00000046  AAD509
CA00000047  AAD510
CA00000047  AAD510
CA00000047  AAD511
CA00000048  AAD511
```

and I would like to find out which rows do not match the following rule:

> NUMBER will always be the same when the SEQUENCE_NUMBER is the same.

So in the above data 'AAD508' will mean the NUMBER value will be the same on each row where the same value appears in the SEQUENCE_NUMBER.

I want to right a query that will bring me back rows where this rule is 
broken. So for example:

```
CA00000047  AAD511
CA00000048  AAD511
```

I don't know where to start with this one, so have no initial SQL i'm afraid.

Thanks

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING etc.

Comment: BTW, your expected result values don't match the sample data.

Comment: The sample data is all correct. There can be rows where there is only one row with a unique SEQUENCE_NUMBER, which means it will therefore have a unique NUMBER value. I guess these will be omitted by the query as the resultant query will be targeting rows that have the same SEQUENCE_NUMBER more than once.

Comment: the sample data were no able to generate the expected result. I added the two additional rows.

Comment: good point @miracle173. Thanks for adding those.

Answer (score 1):

You want to self join on the data to compare each row to all others sharing the same sequence number, and then filter using a with statement to only get rows with non-matching numbers. You did not give a name for the table so I added it as "table_name" below

```
SELECT 
  a.NUMBER,
  a.SEQUENCE_NUMBER
FROM table_name a
INNER JOIN table_name b
ON a.SEQUENCE_NUMBER = b.SEQUENCE_NUMBER
WHERE a.NUMBER <> b.NUMBER
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Threw in the group by to act as a distinct

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.sequence_number = t.sequence_number and
                    t2.number <> t.number
             );
```

If `sequence_numbers()` only had up to two rows, you could get each rule-breaker on one row:

```
select sequence_number, min(number), max(number)
from t
group by sequence_number
having min(number) <> max(number);
```

Or, you could generalize this to get the list of numbers on a single row:

```
select sequence_number, listagg(number, ',') within group (order by number) as numbers
from t
group by sequence_number
having min(number) <> max(number);
```